# accessing .net2.0 dll in a .net 4.0 dll

Tags: c#, .net, com, clr, com-interop

I want to load a .NET 2.0 dll in my .Net4.0 **dll**. I did search for the solution and found the 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' attribute that I can add to my app.config as in this url : [Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018924/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322)

But the problem for me is that, in my case, I am trying to use the .net2.0 dll in my **4.0 DLL and not in an 4.0 exe**. The reason is this 4.0 dll is then used in Excel as an automation add-in.

Currently, when I acccess my .NET 4.0 API (which loads the 2.0 dll for a feature ) from Excel, I get the 'mixed mode 2.0 dll cannot be loaded in 4.0 runtime' which is understandable since COM has loaded the 4.0 CLR and hence cannot load the 2.0 dll.

Somehow I need to make my 4.0 DLL to load the 2.0 runtime. I tried adding a app.config to the 4.0 dll but I guess only .exe reads the app.config by default to load the clr. 
This is what I have in my app.config in the project of 4.0 dll but no use.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

How do I solve this problem to enable my **.NET 4.0 DLL** to use .NET 2.0 dll ?

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: Have you tried just adding the .net 2 dll as you would a normal dll?

Comment: It sounds like it's not a .NET 2.0 DLL - it's a .NET 1.1 DLL.

Comment: The .config file is good, but it needs to be excel.exe.config and copied to the Office directory where excel is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is already done by Hans Passant but he has posted as a comment. Hence, answering this separately in here.

The config has to be called excel.exe.config and should be in the same office directory as excel.exe for this scenario to work.