# How do I create a Video Player for .Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am in the process of writing a basic video player program. I found [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/42801-How-Play-Videos-C-NET-WinForm.aspx) tutorial online, which is exactly the kind of help I was looking for -- except, the tutorial was written for .net 2.0.

This means, for instance, when I originally tried to run the finished program, I got a runtime error identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018924/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322). I fixed that as per the accepted answer, but now I get a *new* bug:

> DLL
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.dll'
>   is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt
>   to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function
>   since doing so can cause the application to hang.

Is there a way to update this tutorial code into something that works with .net 4.0? Or am I better off just finding a new tutorial that's more up-to-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obsolete managed DirectX wrappers do indeed generate this warning.  It is a false warning, the CLR is already loaded.  Debug + Exceptions, expand the Managed Debugging Assistants node and untick LoaderLock.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this, using non-obsolete wrappers?

Comment: Erm, sure, you can add a COM reference to Windows Media Player to your toolbox and drop it on a form. It plays back videos pretty well and takes but a handful of minutes to get going. DirectShow.NET works well too, provided you have the right DS filters installed.  But it sounded like you were trying to do this the non-boring way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use AForge.NET which wraps FFMPEG library so you can work with many kind of video files in C#. Don't use DirecX, use http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html
Building with this framework video player is simple and you don't waste time.